# Yarn package manager: install dependencies from private Bitbucket repository

Tags: node.js, git, bitbucket, yarnpkg

I'm trying to migrate a project **from NPM to Yarn**.

Part of my **node dependencies** are **private packages hosted on Bitbucket** (not published on NPM registry) under the namespace of the company I'm working for.

With NPM I'm able to declare those kind of dependencies with different syntaxes in my `package.json`. Like this:

```
// package.json

"dependencies": {
  ...
  @myCompany/package-name": "bitbucket:bitbucket-username/repo-name.git",
  ...
}
```

But when I run `yarn install` I the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I'm running `yarn v0.23.3` on a MAC OSX.

Is there any further syntax or workaround to let yarn install private repository from bitbucket?

I've scraped into [Yarn's github issues](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bitbucket%20private), but I wasn't able to find any hint 
to decide whether keep on trying or give up.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
"@myCompany/package-name": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/bitbucket-username/repo-name.git",
```

At least, that's what I'm using and it works without any problems.

Comment: It works and accepts a reference to a specific tag/commit, too.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't succeeded to know if this issue with yarn was resolved yet.
So instead here is a workaround :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-git-install

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give it a try with the package you suggested.